# NFC and Android access

Tags: android, nfc

I have a question about NFC tags. I use Android Studio and have written an app that uploads images to a server. Works so far. My goal is to automatically share a picture from the gallery (or other photo app) into my app using an NFC tag. How can I program my NFC tag or app or how could that look like?

Comment: Your app is running on the same device where the gallery is located? Why do you need a NFC rag for sharing ? Or Do you want to write the link of the Server storage to the Tag? Or Do you want to  store the image on the Tag?

Comment: All the apps are located on my device, my idea is to create something like a intent to transfer an image to my app. I want to automate to start this intent (or something) by NFC tag.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not the best i hope that explains the problem